# Expected ')' - SVG Transforms throwing error

Tags: d3.js, svg, transform

I am using D3 to add attributes to a `g` element. I am also using D3-selection-multi to make writing the attributes easier (allows you to pass an object to `.attrs()` function).

using `webpack` and `babel-preset-env`

```
d3.select('g').attrs({
  'class': 'thing',
  'transform-origin': '50% 50%',
  'transform': `translate(${opts.w/2} ${opts.h/2}) rotate(${opts.angle}deg)`
})
```

I keep getting this error: `attribute transform: Expected ')'`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out you can't use **units** in SVG transforms.

`rotate(45deg)` - doesn't work and will throw an error.

`rotate(45)` - expected behavior.

Comment: If I remove units, it seems to break in Safari. Any fix for that? see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49576545/error-text-attribute-transform-expected-translate-50-50

Answer (score -1):

Try switching "attr" to "style"

```
d3.select('g').attrs('class': 'thing')
    .style('transform-origin', '50% 50%')
    .style('transform', `translate(${opts.w/2} ${opts.h/2}) rotate(${opts.angle}deg)`);
```