# Error: <text> attribute transform: Expected ')', "translate(-50%,-50%)"

Tags: svg

I have an SVG that contains this line:

```
<text transform="translate(-50%,-50%)" text-anchor="middle" class="st11 st13" x="389" y="440" font-family="Roboto Condensed" style="fill: #ffffff">
    99
</text>
```

In Chrome I get this error but it seems to be fine on Safari

> Error:  attribute transform: Expected ')', "translate(-50%,-50%)".

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098397/how-to-translate-an-svg-group-by-a-percentage-of-the-viewport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SVG 1.1 [transform values must be numbers](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute) i.e. no units are allowed.

In SVG 2 transforms are supposed to be [CSS properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#typedef-transform-function) with [extra rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#svg-transform) to preserve backwards compatibility for the unitless SVG 1.1 case.

Perhaps Safari has implemented SVG 2 transforms, whereas Chrome has not yet done so. SVG 2 is a work in progress for all browsers. The most cross-browser way of doing things would be to omit units or use an [alternative way of producing a percentage transform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17103928/1038015) if you need it.

Comment: Omitting units, simply does not work in Safari. Using units works on most browsers, but throws an error in e.g. Chrome.

Comment: CSS transforms require units, SVG transforms require an absence of units. I assume you're mistakenly talking about CSS transforms when this question is about SVG transforms.